# Insert Dictionary elements into SQL table as rows using IDatareader and SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I need to improve dramatically the execution time of a process wich currently is just like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, SingleElement> elements_buffer;

// ... Create and load values into "elements_buffer"
// (string, Datetime, double)

string query = "INSERT INTO Tests.dbo.test_table "
    + "(element_name,element_init,element_width) VALUES";

SingleElement element_aux;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMS_IN_DICT; i++)
{
    element_aux = elements_buffer[i];

    query = query
        + "('"
        + element_aux.name
        + "','"
        + element_aux.init
        + "',"
        + element_aux.width
        + ")";

    if (i < MAX_ELEMS_IN_DICT+1) {
        query = query + ",";
    }
}

// ... Execute the query
```

I was going to use `Datatable` for the new version, but I've been reading about using `SqlBulkCopy` together with `IDatareader`, as mentioned in:

[SqlBulkCopy performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526797/sqlbulkcopy-performance)

[C# loops and mass insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411353/c-sharp-loops-and-mass-insert)

It looks like to me a better choice for my code, but can't get to figure it out how to code it, though I would like to use it.

Can I have some help with the translated code, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead of string concatenations. This kind of concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Actually it's not accessible from the Internet and security it's not a problem; I appreciate your comment anyway, but if you could help me with my question it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have figured out, you need to implement custom [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx).
As your source is Dictionary - only few relatively simple method/properties such as int FieldCount, bool Read(), object Get(int i) should be implemented.

You may find useful examples ([a simple one](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2011/12/22/using-a-custom-idatareader-to-stream-data-into-a-database/)) of custom IDataReader implementations by googling *sqlbulkcopy custom idatareader*.

Also keep in mind that SqlBulkCopy ignores triggers, foreign keys and other constraints and is not able to handle exceptions.